# Get all child categories only of custom taxonomy | Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get list of only child categories of custom taxonomy, but getting output as all parent and child terms.

```
$countries = get_categories(array(
    'hide_empty'      => true,
    'taxonomy' => 'locations-category',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'         => 'locations-category',
            'terms'            => 0,
            'field'            => 'parent',
            'compare'         => '!='
        )
    )
));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($countries);
echo "</pre>";`
```

Tried this as well but getting error as undefined variable:

```
$categories = get_terms('locations-category', 'parent!=0');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($countries);
echo "</pre>";
```

Basically I want to get categories where `'parent' != 0`

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use PHP to filter the results from `get_category()` (untested):

```php
$terms = get_category( array(
    ...
) );

$child_terms = array_filter( $terms, static function ( $term ) {
    return 0 !== $term->parent;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$taxonomy = 'your_custom_taxonomy'; // Replace with your actual custom taxonomy name

$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => false, // Set to true if you want to exclude empty terms
));
$child_categories = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $child_ids = get_term_children($term->term_id, $taxonomy);
    
    foreach ($child_ids as $child_id) {
        $child_category = get_term_by('id', $child_id, $taxonomy);
        $child_categories[] = $child_category;
    }
}
print_r($child_categories);
Please make sure to replace 'your_custom_taxonomy' with the actual name of your custom taxonomy in the code.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).